# How to launch a jar file with c++ exe?

Tags: c++, jar

I have a file .jar and i want to launch it with a c++ exe.

I have written inside the file exe this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   system("cd E:\\Test\\Test 1.0");
   system("java -jar Test.jar");

}
```

But it gives me this output: "Unable to access jarfile Test.jar"

How could i solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you use `CreateProcess(..)` instead of using `system(..)`? This enables you to control exactly how the new process is being created (command line, working directory, ...) and you get a handle to the created process with which you can wait for the process to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work since the full path can't have spaces you will have to specify the full path like this "E:\\Test\Test 1.0\Test.jar" including the double quotes " "

```
  int main()
  {

  system("java -jar \"E:\\\\Test\\Test 1.0\\Test.jar\"");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each call to "system" is independant to the former one, so your second call to system has not the working directory you think it has, but a default one. You either need to do everything regarding the execution of the Jar in one system call or, much better and easier, simply provide the absolute path to the Jar in your system call.

> Invokes the command processor to execute a command.

[system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)

There's no sentence about that the command processor is persistant for different calls to system or that one and the same us used, so state is preserved etc. That's simypl not the case, one call most of the times directly refers to one execution of cmd.exe on Windows or any default shell on Linux or whatever.

Comment: With the full path it gives me "Unable to access jarfile E:\Test\Test"

Comment: @clau_ste Because you have spaces in your path and need to quote it, you already have that error in your first system-call as well. Remember that a shell is used to execute shell commands.

Comment: If i use "java%20-jar%20E.\\Test\\Test.jar" it says that the synthax is wrong

Comment: @clau_ste Your are really missing basics which you could easily search for yourself... Just start cmd.exe, type "java" and have a look at how your commandline needs to look like, which arguments may be used, which options and especially what is the path. And the path and only the path needs to be quoted: java -jar "..." And it's "E:", not "E." as well.

Comment: I know what you have written, i've also tested with "java -jar" and the point was a mistake, i know it's ":".

Comment: And with "java -jar" it says the same error, unable to access jar file

Comment: @clau_ste Because it's wrong of course, that's what I said before. Please make yourself familar with basics on how to start applications in cmd.exe, because that's what is getting ultimately called in your case. I already provided you the correct solution in my former comment. Using  "%20" is wrong, quotes around "java -jar" is wrong, just use quotes around the path.

Comment: How can i add the quotes around the path? the string passed inside system can't be "java -jar "E:\\blablabla"");

Comment: I founded it, i just add \042 that correspond to " in ascii

Comment: @clau_ste Looks like you need basics for C++ as well: Quotes in strings simply need to be escaped. http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape